# How to show the value which is used inside overflow hidden using z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, z-index

I want to show the anchor tag using z-index which is inside the overflow :hidden filed
Please find the fiddle:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna123/63s5B/)**

```
<div class="testclass">
 sdhva sjd asds,adb asdbn asd
    asnd vasndb v
    asdj vas ndv
    asjd asjd 
    <a href="#" class="bx-next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't, if it's hidden is hidden

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not the way to provide link for you fiddle.. and the second thing is you cannot achieve both overflow:hidden and show only one content inside that div[overflow:auto/scroll is exception].. If you really want to show only the link y dont you place it at begining..??

**Or else place link in different div.. So that it will appear right under it.. All you need to do is proper designing...**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/63s5B/1/

Added `position: absolute;` to `testclass` and `position: relative;` to `bx-next`

Comment: Dat really doesnt cope upwell at times where there are more contents inside the div..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show the anchor, if it's inside a hidden area.

You must move it out of the area to show it, or make the area visible.